# Array size declaring dynamically in c and c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm passing the array size dynamically through a variable named size, it's working fine in c but not in c++. Please tell me the reason, Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    int size;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int i ;

      int *a[size];
      cout<<"Enter size";
      cin >> size;


     for(i =0; i < size ;i++)
      {
        cout<<"Enter value:" ;
        cin>>a[i] ;
      }

    for(i=0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
       cout<<a[i]<< " ";
     }
     system("PAUSE");   
     return 0;
   }
```

I have executed the same program with proper I/O changes, its executed properly.

Also please help me in understanding how compiler is behaving in this case at the time of array declaration.

Comment: C++ does not support variable length arrays. `size` would have to be a compile time constant.

Comment: seriously, your code is broken on many levels. I don't see how your C code could ever have worked.

Comment: hey karoly, could you explain in detail, broken on many levels?

Comment: Well, it seems like you are attempting to create an array of pointers with an indeterminate size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please tell me the reason

The reason is that C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays. Perhaps you are looking for `std::vector<int>` (likely) or `new int` (unlikely).

> Also please help me in understanding how compiler is behaving in this case at the time of array declaration.

Just like it behaves in any other case: it parses the source text and outputs machine code of which the semantics correspond to that of the source code. It's just that the size of a variable-length array is not hard-coded as a constant, instead it is stored in a register or on the stack (like some sort of "variable"), and size calculations (pointer arithmetic, in particular) are performed agains that stored value.

Comment: hi H2CO3, so, in C, the memory is allocated for an array of variable length only after the array length variable is initialized, as you told before it is stored in a register/stack, after memory allocation where it would be stored? in the heap?

Comment: @Mahesh No, why would it be like so? If you write `int arr[size]` when `size` is uninitialized, you will have a quite randomly sized array. And that won't change even if you assigned something to `size` **after** the declaration of the array.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but u mean in c if i declare   int a[size], with an uninitialized size variable, will it become a random sized array even after i initialized size variable afterwards ?

Comment: @Mahesh Well, what else would happen? Are you aware of the concept of "sequence"?

Comment: No, could you pls help me with the link?

Comment: @Mahesh Huh, that's tough. Haven't found a Wikipedia article, here's what Encyclopedia Britannica says about it: [link](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/1086517/sequence)

Comment: @H2CO3 According to the C standard, "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate". According to Annex J2 this seems to be undefined behaviour...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Well yes, but how is it relevant?

Comment: You're the one who mentioned `int arr[size]` where `size` is presumably a variable with automatic storage duration that is not initialised explicitly... Giving that behaviour a definition by stating that it declares a randomly sized object contradicts the very nature of "undefined behaviour". I just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Ah, OK, I see what you mean. Well, reading an uninitialized variable is not, strictly, undefined behavior, but it yields an unspecified value.

Comment: Annex J.2p1: The behavior is undeﬁned in the following circumstances: ... — The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I mean, C++ has no VLAs whatsoever, so it would be pointless to argue about that if we were talking about C++. But I guess you were nevertheless - deducing that from the fact that I was wrong, I feel this must be C++.

Comment: No. Which language was Mahesh asking about? Which standard was I quoting from? This information is available by scrolling up and reading. I'm done, here, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code tries to allocate an amount of memory from an uninitialized variable `size`. Its value is assigned only later:

```
int a[size];
/* ... */
cin >> size;
```

If you switch the order of these statements, it might do what you want, if your C++ compiler has an extension for variable length arrays. A more portable and generally preferable solution would be:

```
cin >> size;
std::vector<int> a(size);
```

*Edit:* You probably want an `int[]` not `*int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create variable length arrays in c++. try using vectors instead

Answer (score 1):

There are no VLAs in C++.

If you want to write your code to be used in a C++ project, then write your code in C++ (use `std::vector` instead of VLAs) or write your code in C, compile it with a C compiler and use your linker to link to it from your C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

`int *a[size];` by this statement you want to create a array of size `size` , but you have not initialized the variable `size`.C++ doesn't support variable length array.You can do it by this:

```
int size;
cin>>size;
int *a[size];
```

or just use STL `vector` which allocates memory dynamically.

```
vector<int>a;
```

and to put value in the vector just push back the values

```
a.push_back(56);
```

For more about vector check out this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)